# How to get Gridster to reposnse faster to drag events on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-events, gridster

I have setup a basic Gridster.js demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/dvPaF/

My goal is to make it more "responsive" to drag events. Right now there is a noticeable delay between dragging an element with a finger and actual element movement. Once the dragging starts though, the delay disappears.

I debugged the code to the point where this [event](https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.gridster.js#L552):

```
this.$body.on(pointer_events.move, function(mme){ 
  => first time fast, second time with delay <=
  // I have commented out the "distance" logic
}
```

fires fast the first time, but then there is the delay for the second time. I have commented out the distance logic in the above event.

I am testing this on various Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance of the drag event on mobile you can use [this library.](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)

It will help in easing out the delay and you can include all the UI events on mobile.